# A class to help access a chunk of memory

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

I need a class to help me access a chunk of memory

So far I have this

```
class ABSet
{
    private byte[] _raw;
    public ABSet(byte[] RawData)
    {
        _raw=RawData;
    }
    public double A
    {
        get
        {
            return BitConverter.ToDouble(_raw, 2);
        }
     }
     public double B
     {
         get
         {
             return BitConverter.ToDouble(_raw, 10);
         }
     }
}
```

Now I would like to do something like this

```
class ABSetCollection
{
    private byte[] _raw;
    public ABSetCollcetion(byte[] RawData)
    {
        _raw=RawData;
    }
    public ABSet this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            // This Part Is What I Want To Figure Out
        }
     } 
}
```

I know I could put `return new ABSet(_raw);` but I feel like there must be a solution that requires less dynamic allocation.

P.S. The reason I want to use properties is because I am binding to them in my GUI

Comment: What's wrong with using `List<ABSet>`?

Comment: Just feel like it's a lot of storage overhead. I am trying to come up with a solution that only needs one instance of `ABSet`

Comment: Why not keep it simple and add the indexer to `ABSet`?

Comment: What would this look like. I thought about it and I figured it would need something like `private int index` that it would modify and return itself

Comment: i think the question is - what are you trying to do? You want a collection of ABSets? Or do you want an ABSet that looks deeper into that byte array?

Comment: The `byte[]` exists. I just want a tool to get the data I need out and present it to the gui. Internally it is a repeating structure that the number of may change(known at compile time) but the relationship is fixed

Answer (score 0):

Rather than just accepting an array of bytes, change it so you get an offset too.  Then you'll be able to get that to work.

```
class ABSet
{
    public const int ABSetSize = 20; // or whatever the size

    private readonly byte[] _data;
    private readonly int _offset;
    public ABSet(byte[] data, int offset = 0)
    {
        _data = data;
        _offset = offset;
    }

    const int AOffset = 2;
    public double A => BitConverter.ToDouble(_data, _offset + AOffset);

    const int BOffset = 10;
    public double B => BitConverter.ToDouble(_data, _offset + BOffset);
}

class ABSetCollection
{
    private readonly byte[] _data;
    private readonly int _offset;
    public ABSetCollection(byte[] data, int offset = 0)
    {
        _data = data;
        _offset = offset;
    }

    public ABSet this[int index] => new ABSet(_data, _offset + index * ABSet.ABSetSize);
}
```

Comment: On the other hand, you could save your self a lot of time by just mapping it out to a struct with an explicit layout.